# Auto scrolling on page load issue

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

I have an issue on this page (http://www.loop-branding.com/).
After the page gets loaded it scrolls down to a certain point.

I don't know why this happens!

Thank you very much for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `autofocus=""` attribute from the input tag

```html
<input class="parsley-validated" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Nome e cognome" autofocus="" data-required="true" data-show-errors="true" data-error-message="Campo obbligatorio" type="text"/>
```